# Mongo DB (version 2.6) configure nssize (namespace issues with large number of collections)

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB version 2.6.. Lately I had an issue with mongo running out of namespace size when the number of collections increased suddenly due to a burst of data..

After reading, the default nssize is 16 MB which means around 24k different collections.. To increase this I need to configure nssize.. but however I have am not able to configure it.. 2.6 manual says that we can use a YAML file to configure this.. I tried -

```
#keep nssize around 1gb
storage:
    nssize: 1000
```

but apparently it did not work.. **mongod** failed identifying this as an unknown configuration..

When I put it as a flag -

```
--nssize xyz
```

it works..
Any ideas where am I going wrong? How to put this in conf file? The following do not work -

```
storage:
    nssize: abc
```

OR

```
storage:
    ns: xyz
```

Comment: looks like you need to use camelCase: nsSize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs show the reason: in config file the syntax is with capitalized S: nsSize.

See: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.nsSize

Comment: You are right.. horrible! --nssize this works.. but in conf file you have to make it camel case

Comment: I agree it's inconsistent, but I believe it's the command line parameter that was "non-standard" - at some point they started all being camel case, but the ones that predate that decision are still all lowercase.  probably should be aliased to camel case, maybe I'll file a bug.